# How to call the method inside a page in Asp.net website Using scheduler that is running in some other thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

How to call the method inside a page in Asp.net website  Using scheduler that is running in some other thread?

Currently i am getting HttpContext.Current value as null .

Here is my code.

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["isSendMail"] = "True";
System.Web.UI.Page page = System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("/ChecklistList.aspx", typeof(System.Web.UI.Page)) as System.Web.UI.Page;
page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
```